# JQuery stops working when adding link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning JQuery and was working with JQuery script which slides text through pictures:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var currentImg = 1,
                totalImages = 4
                loopTime = 1000,
                intervalId = null;


            function displayTitle(imgNbr) {
                $('.title').hide();
                $('#image'+imgNbr).prev('div').show();
            }

            $('img').on('mouseover', function() {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                displayTitle($(this).parent().attr('id').substring(5));
            }).on('mouseout', function() {
                currentImg = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(5);
                startLoop();
            })

            function startLoop() {
                intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    displayTitle(currentImg);
                    currentImg = ((currentImg == totalImages) ? 1 : parseInt(currentImg)+1);
                }, loopTime);
            }
            startLoop();
        });
   </script>
```

But when I try to add [a href="#"] tag between [div] and image tags it stops working. Could you please help me to fix it. Thanks.

```
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 1</div>
    <div class="img" id="image1"><a href="#"><img src="images/image1.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 2</div>
    <div class="img" id="image2"><a href="#"><img src="images/image2.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>    

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 3</div>
    <div class="img" id="image3"><a href="#"><img src="images/image3.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"it stops working."_ Can you elaborate more please? and a demo could be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
displayTitle($(this).parent().attr('id').substring(5));
```

to:

```
displayTitle($(this).parents('div').attr('id').substring(5));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zAZst/1/)**.

Answer (score 1):

It stops working because the div is no longer the preceding sibling.  You should change the call to use `prevAll('div')` to select all preceding siblings that match the div selector.

The `prev` function only matches the first sibling before the current element and then only if it matches the selector. In this case, you've added an intervening element, the anchor tag, and so the div is no longer the first preceding sibling and the selector matches nothing.  `PrevAll` considers all the preceding siblings matching the selector.  In your case there's only one.  If you change your mark up further to introduce additional divs, you'd have to adjust the selector to choose the appropriate one out of the set.

```
function displayTitle(imgNbr) {
    $('.title').hide();
     $('#image'+imgNbr).prevAll('div').show();
}
```